# Variable Chart Range

Tags: excel, vba

I want the chart range to change if the Sheet1 range changes. The range begins on row 5 and can end at any other row. Tried this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Change_Chart()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim x As Range, y As Range

Set x = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5", Range("B5").End(xlDown))
Set y = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Q5", Range("Q5").End(xlDown))

ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range(x, y)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It compiles, but when it runs the error says "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed"

Comment: use a named range. vba seems over kill

Answer (score 0):

Try with this change of your last line of code:

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range(ChartRangex.address & _
                             "," & ChartRangey.Address)
```

or this modification:

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Union(ChartRangex, ChartRangey).Address)
```

EDIT: I have an idea regarding `Set line` error (according to comment below):

I have and idea what could be wrong. Change the `Set line` into something like this:

```
Set x = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5"), Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").End(xlDown))`
```

and do the same with the other `Set line`.

Comment: @Max, show more of your code then, including variable declaration.

Comment: @Max, see my edition in the answer- I have an idea what is wrong and how to solve it.